# app crashes if user did not press anything

Tags: android, crash, android-studio-2.2

My app (brain trainer is similar to my app) crashes if the user didn't press on anything. i tried to fix it by adding the if statement and check the num of questions , however that didn't help.

Dose anyone have an idea what should I do/try?

```
public void playAgain (View view){ //after the timer is finished , and we call it also in oncrate fist play



        score = 0;
        numOfQuestions = 0;
        timerTextView.setText("30s");
       // resultTextView.setText("");
        pointsTextView.setText("");
        scoreTextView.setText("");


        correctTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        wrongTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        resultTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pointsTextView.setText("0/0");
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        menuButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gridScore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        scoreTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 The if statement when timer finished:

public void onFinish() {
    //resultTextView.setText("Your Score is: ");
    resultTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (numOfQuestions==0){
        score=0;
    scoreTextView.setText("0/0");
    } else {
        scoreTextView.setText(Integer.toString(score) + "/" + Integer.toString(numOfQuestions));
    }
    scoreTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    gridScore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    timerTextView.setText("0s");
    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    menuButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    resultGridLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    menuButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    correctTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    wrongTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: what is the crash log?

Comment: Hi abdul, thank you for answering I found my problem I divide a number with ziro